# /bin/dash cannot find hostname

Tags: bash, hostname, dash-shell

I have newly installed a remastered ubuntu 12.10. after installation I ran a script to make a standard user and do some other works. now when I log into the new standard user and open terminal, it only shows a `$` mark and doesnt show `username@hostname$`.

it can return `whoami` but doesnt return anything for `echo $HOSTNAME`
the interesting thing is when I run bash, everything is ok, but when I run dash(which is default in ubuntu) I see the problem.

I've tried `dpkg-reconfigure dash` but nothing changed.

can anyone guess what is happened to my system!
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use bash instead of dash since the former is far better for interactive use.

The shell for the new user is probably set to `/bin/dash`, you just have to create the new user specifing the shell you want using the `--shell` option for the `adduser` command. 
To change the shell for an alredy created user you can use the command `chsh`.

Comment: but the administrator user uses dash with no problem; so the standard user must be capable of using dash, too. what is the problem with dash?

Comment: dash is not intended for interactive use, it is used on Debian-like systems to execute startup script since it's much faster than bash. For interactive use i recommend using bash. If you really want to use dash you have to configure it by yourself. Copying the administrator `.profile` file could be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks toro, I checked and saw that the admin user uses bash too. so I changed to bash with chsh (as you said). it solved the problem. but why doesnt dash return hostname? a bit strange!

Comment: The variable $HOSTNAME is specific to bash, dash don't define it by default. You can see the dash manual page for reference.